# Why $\alpha |u|^p+\beta \leq \gamma |u|$ implies that $u$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $u:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a function. We suppose that there are $\alpha >0,\gamma >0$ and $\beta \in \mathbb R$ s.t. 
$$\alpha |u(x)|^p+\beta \leq \gamma |u(x)|,$$
for all $x$ where $p>1$. Why does it implies that $u$ is uniformly bounded ?

Comment: Pick a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers such that $|u(x_n)| \to \infty$. Then $|u(x_n)| = o(|u(x_n)|^p) $ as $n\to \infty$ because $p>1$

Comment: Pick no sequence whatsoever but note that, for every $x$, $$\alpha |u(x)|^p\leqslant \gamma |u(x)|+|\beta|$$ hence, either $|u(x)|\leqslant1$, or $$\alpha |u(x)|^p\leqslant (\gamma+|\beta|)\,|u(x)|$$ and  then $$|u(x)|^{p-1}\leqslant (\gamma+|\beta|)/\alpha$$ To sum up, $|u|$ is uniformly bounded by $$M=\max\{1,((\gamma+|\beta|/\alpha)^{1/(p-1)}\}$$

Comment: We can think of the behavior of the function $f(y)=\alpha y^p-\gamma y +\beta$, $y\in \{|u(x)| :x\in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: @Did: Why don't you write that as an answer? It is the only approach presently on this page that gives an explicit bound.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(y)=\alpha y^p-\gamma y +\beta$, $y\in \{|u(x)| :x\in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Here to show $\sup\{y: f(y)\leq 0 \}$ is finite.

We can start with all $y\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Note that, $f'(y)=0$ gives us the solution $y^*=(\frac{\gamma}{\alpha p})^{\frac{1}{p-1}}$

$f''(y^*)=\alpha p(p-1)(\frac{\gamma}{\alpha p})^{\frac{p-2}{p-1}}>0$.

Then $f(y)$ has only one minima which is $y^*$, and as $y\to\infty$, $f(y)\to\infty$, since $|\beta|<\infty$. Hence $\sup\{y\in \mathbb{R}: f(y)\leq 0 \}$ is finite. Hence $\sup\{y\in \{|u(x)| :x\in \mathbb{R} \}: f(y)\leq 0 \}$ is finite.

Comment: Your argument is slightly convoluted but the idea is nice, and it also yields the sharp bound on $|u(x)|$: $$|u(x)|\le C=\sup\left\{ f(y)\le 0\ :\ y\in \mathbb R\right\}$$ I say that the argument is convoluted because I do not see the necessity of studying critical points: the fact that $\lim_{|y|\to \infty} f(y)=+\infty$ already tells us that $C<\infty$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I just gave the argument that $f(y^*)<0$, $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)=+\infty$, and $|\beta|<\infty$, then we will have $C<\infty$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I understood what are you saying, I find out the unique minima to ensure that the above comment will hold definitely. We do not have a local maxima in the set $\{f(y)\leq 0:y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Although now I am thinking it may not be needed!!

Comment: Yes, I think it is not needed. The fact that the limit is infinite implies, by definition, that there exists a $R>0$ such that $f(y)>0$ for all $|y|\ge R$. This means exactly that $\sup\{ f(y)\le 0\ :\ y\in \mathbb R\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing both sides by $|u|$ we can write this as $$\alpha |u(x)|^{p-1} + \beta |u(x)|^{-1} \le \gamma.$$ If $u$ was unbounded then there would be a sequence $x_n$ such that $|u(x_n)| \to \infty$, and thus (since $p-1 >0$) we would have $\alpha|u(x_n)|^{p-1} + \beta|u(x_n)|^{-1} \to \infty$, contradicting the bound by $\gamma$.